# To create a new folder in Qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to create a new folder in Qml…So I found out it via Qt…..so i want to integrate this below Qt C++ with Qml…..How is it possible…

```
    QDir dir(“path/to/dir”);
    if (!dir.exists()) 
    { 
     dir.mkpath(”.”);
    }
```

Or else,is there any options for creating new folder directly in Qml…Please suggest a solutions.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to create a directory directly from QML nor JavaScript. You will have to create an object in C++ and "export" it (make visible) to QML. Than you can call this object's method from your QML code and it will create the directory.

The basic idea of connecting C++ and QML is covered here:
[Reading and writing files in QML](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Reading_and_writing_files_in_QML)
The only thing you'd have to change is to exchange write method for createDir (or whatever you want) and insert your code.

Another way to do it is to set contextProperty ex.

```cpp
QQmlContext *context;
context = viewer.rootContext();

context->setContextProperty("DirManager", &dManager);
```

(where DirManager is your class) and use macro `Q_INVOKABLE` before the return type of your method.